# How to submit a swap using EIP-1559 style?

Tags: 0x

I'd like to submit a swap to 0x using an eip1559 style transaction, but am unable to figure out how this should be done.
Can someone provide some guidance on how to achive this using web3, in a typescript environment?

Is there any custom parameter that needs to be sent to the API to obtain correct responses from 0x?

Or is it simply sufficient to replace the gas price with the eip1559 style values?
What about the gas estimates? Can these be ignored?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, only the gas price and the transaction type need to be changed, if you don't want to take the default one (web3 will send a type2/eip1559 tx by default) : you should add `maxFeePerGas` and `maxPriorityFeePerGas`, as well as specify this is a `type: 2` transaction, ending in a payload like this :

```
const payload = {
  from: ...,
  to: ...,
  maxFeePerGas: xxx,
  maxPriorityFeePerGas: xxx,
  type: 2,
  data: 0x...
}
```

See this post by Alchemy for bigger example : https://docs.alchemy.com/alchemy/guides/eip-1559/send-tx-eip-1559